# How to put Image (Blob) from mySQL to XML in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, utf-8

I have the following code, but it does not work well to get Iamge data (Encoding error). I have to change anything to get the Iamge. Thank.

```
<?php
$config['table_name'] = "ResultSet";
mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
@mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Không thể kết nối `enter code here`database");
$xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$root_element = $config['table_name']."s";
$xml         .= "<$root_element>";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `nhom3` ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);



if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $xml .= '<ResultSet>';
    $xml .= '<Name>'.$row["Name"].'</Name>'; //Text
    $xml .= '<Body>'.$row["Body"].'</Body>'; //Text
    $xml .= '<Iamge>'.$row["Iamge"].'</Iamge>'; //Blob
        //header('content-type = image/jpeg');
    $xml .= '</ResultSet>';
        }
}


$xml .= "</$root_element>";
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo $xml;
?>
```

Comment: well xml files are text files, they dont contain binary (image) data. base64 might be an option. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to extract xml string to display text and images on the screen WP8 phones, please give me solution. I want to put text and images on the server, retrieving through php xml format and then read the display.